# Developing using PyCharm in Docker Container on AWS Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, pycharm

I use PyCharm Professional to develop python.

I am able to connect the PyCharm run/debugs GUI to local Docker image's python interpreter and run local code using the Docker Container python environment libraries, eg. via the procedure described here: [Configuring Remote Interpreter via Docker](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html).

I am also able to SSH into AWS instances with PyCharm and connect to remote python interpreters there, which maps files from my local project into a remote directory and again allows me to run a GUI stepping through remote code as though it was local, eg. via the procedure described here: [Configuring Remote Interpreters via SSH](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html).

I have a Docker image on Docker hub that I would like to deploy to an AWS instance, and then connect my local PyCharm GUI to the environment inside the remote container, but I can't see how to do this, can anybody help me?

[EDIT] Once proposal that has been made is to put an SSH Server inside the remote container and connect my local PyCharm directly into the container via SSH, for example [as described here](https://davidraleigh.github.io/2017/06/27/Debugging-a-Remote-Docker-Container-with-PyCharm.html). It's one solution but has been [extensively criticised elsewhere](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/) - is there a more canonical solution?

Comment: [This is a related feature request for PyCharm.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19752)

Answer (score 7):

After doing a bit of research, I came to the conclusion that installing an SSH server inside my container and logging in via the PyCharm SSH remote interpreter was the best thing to do, despite concerns raised elsewhere. I managed it as follows.

The Dockerfile below will create an image with an SSH server inside that you can SSH into. It also has anaconda/python, so it's possible to run a notebook server inside and connect to that in the usual way for Jupyter degubbing. Note that it's got a plain-text password (screencast), you should definitely enable key login if you're using this for anything sensitive.

It will take local libraries and install them into your package library inside the container, and optionally you can pull repos from GitHub as well (register for an API key in GitHub if you want to do this so you don't need to enter a plain text password). It also requires you to create a plaintext `requirements.txt` containing all of the other packages you will need to be pip installed.

Then run build command to create the image, and run to create a container from that image. In the Dockerfile we expose the SSH through the container's port 22, so let's hook that up to an unused port on the AWS instance - this is the port we will SSH through. Also add another port pairing if you want to use Jupyter from your local machine at any point:

```
docker build -t your_image_name .
```

don't miss the `.` at the end - it's important!

```
docker run -d -p 5001:22 -p8889:8889 --name=your_container_name your_image_name
```

Nb. you will need to bash into the container (`docker exec -it xxxxxxxxxx bash`) and turn Jupyter on, with `jupyter notebook`.

Dockerfile:

```
ROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server

# Load an ssh server. Change root username and password. By default in debian, password login is prohibited,
# go into the file that controls this and make a change to allow password login
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN /etc/init.d/ssh restart

# Install git, so we can pull in some repos
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y git

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

# Install the requirements and the libraries we need (from a requirements.txt file)
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

# These are local libraries, add them (assuming a setup.py)
ADD your_libs_directory /your_libs_directory
RUN python3 -m pip install /your_libs_directory
RUN python3 your_libs_directory/setup.py install

# Adding git repos (optional - assuming a setup.py)
git clone https://git_user_name:git_API_token@github.com/YourGit/git_repo.git
RUN python3 -m pip install /git_repo
RUN python3 git_repo/setup.py install

# Cleanup
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Comment: When you say AWS instance, do you mean `EC2`? Did you have to open any port on the `EC2`?

Comment: PyCharm can list the packages installed, but I tried to open a Python console I get the error: `Couldn't connect to console process.`